# Disable coupons for subscription products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to disable coupon codes for my WooCommerce Subscriptions that I have set up through the "all products for subscription" add on. I've tried the snippet below but it's not targeting subscription products added through the "all products for subscription" plugin. I could be in the wrong direction completely.

I have a test product [here](https://www.montkush.com/shop/cbd-oil/mint-cbd-oil-test/)

Below is my code attempt:

```
function sw_wc_apfs_disable_on_susbcription( $is_valid, $product, $instance, $values ) {

if ( ! empty( $values[ ‘wcsatt_data’][ ‘active_subscription_scheme’ ] ) ) {
$is_valid = false;
}

return $is_valid;
}
```

It doesn't work… Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is a bit incomplete, as the hook is missing, from your code. Also there are some mistakes in your code.

There is only 3 arguments `woocommerce_coupon_is_valid` hook, so you need to loop through cart items instead.

**Here below are 2 code versions:**

1). For subscription products using **"All products for subscription"** add on *(code is commented)*:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 'disable_coupons_for_subscription_products', 10, 3 );
function disable_coupons_for_subscription_products( $is_valid, $coupon, $discount ){
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Check for subscription products using "All products for subscription" add on
        if ( isset($cart_item['wcsatt_data']['active_subscription_scheme']) 
        && ! empty($cart_item['wcsatt_data']['active_subscription_scheme']) ) {
            $is_valid = false; // Subscription product found: Make coupons "not valid"
            break; // Stop and exit from the loop
        }
    }
    return $is_valid;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

---

2). For normal subscription products *(code is commented)*:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 'disable_coupons_for_subscription_products', 10, 3 );
function disable_coupons_for_subscription_products( $is_valid, $coupon, $discount ){
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Check for subscription products
        if( in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_type(), array('subscription', 'subscription_variation') ) ) {
            $is_valid = false; // Subscription product found: Make coupons "not valid"
            break; // Stop and exit from the loop
        }
    }
    return $is_valid;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.