# Disable coupons for subscription products but allow coupons for one-time purchase in the same cart in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, subscription, woocommerce-subscriptions

Currently using "WooCommerce Subscriptions" and "all Products on Subscription plugins". I can't use coupons when having both one-time purchase and subscription product in the same cart. I would like to allow coupons on “One-time purchase” and don’t allow coupons on “products on subscription” when they are in the same cart.

I've tried [Disable coupons for subscription products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64230274/disable-coupons-for-subscription-products-in-woocommerce/64232067#64232067) answer code, but it's not allowing coupons on one-time purchase products.

SCREENSHOTS:

- [Cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xenp.png)
- [Check Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jc1T.png)

Comment: Sorry but I just tested the code and it still works perfectly, only disallowing coupons if there is a product with subscription in cart. If there are no products with subscription, coupon get successfully applied for One-time purchase products... Now for sure the code is not applying a discount only on One-time purchase items only when there are mixed items from both types… You will have to code it yourself as this requires something different and much more complicated.